# What would a planet with a notably high sulfur content but otherwise Earthlike composition be like?

Tags: science-based, planets, environment, chemistry

I'm currently working on making a planet with mostly Earthlike chemistry, but I want to throw something into the mix to make it distinctly different from Earth and most likely uninhabitable to Earthlike life.

Namely, the first substance I came across that could add some interesting chemistry was sulfur. I'm no chemist, however, and what research I have done on the subject has been somewhat inconclusive. I'd like to know what a planet with an Earthlike composition, but much higher sulfur content, would be like - namely, the chemistry of its atmosphere, oceans,  and exactly how it would effect the development and biology of life on its surface.

### Presume the following:

- The composition of the planet's atmosphere is otherwise Earthlike (~70-80% nitrogen, ~20-30% oxygen, >1% CO2, so on and so forth).
- The composition of the planet's crust, mantle, and core is also similarly Earthlike except for one factor: a much higher amount of sulfur in the mantle and crust. It is expelled to the surface by large amounts of volcanic activity.
- The planet's surface is over 90% water oceans.
- The planet is relatively cold, but due to numerous factors does not get cold enough to constitute a world-wide ice age. It does, however, suffer extreme seasonal shifts and flooding due to an elliptical orbit around the system's primary star, which in the short summer heats up the surface and causes enough icemelt to flood most land.
- Sulfur content is high enough to have a notable impact on the environment, but is not so high that the relative proportions of other substances in the atmosphere are disrupted too much. (I've purposely avoided hashing out hard numbers - you can fudge the numbers a bit to make the setting work, if necessary)

What research I have done suggests a couple of things. First, the atmosphere would probably have a notable amount of sulfur dioxide, which would make it toxic to Earthlike life and could cause acid rain. Secondly, the ocean would also have a notable amount of sulfur, and what I found said that it would mostly be in the form of sulfurous acid - however, what I could find was mostly inconclusive, and disagreed exactly what sort of chemicals would be floating around in the ocean and what effects they might have. I'm not sure if any of what I've found so far is completely correct, since it's mostly speculation at this point.

### Here are the things I'm most curious about:

- What chemicals and compounds would large amounts of sulfur create when exposed to an Earthlike atmosphere and Earthlike oceans?
- How would those chemicals effect the environment, ie temperature, weather, visibility, and so on?
- Would those chemicals be toxic to Earthlike life, and if so, how? If a human went walking or swimming around without their spacesuit on, what terrible end would they meet?
- How would lifeforms with otherwise mostly Earthlike chemistry (carbon-based, water solvent, animals take in O2 and release CO2 and plants vice versa, so on and so forth) evolve to survive this? Bonus points if you can think of ways they'd use these chemicals to their benefit.
- What percentage of sulfur would be enough so as to have a notable impact on the environment as described above, but otherwise leave the composition of the planet mostly Earthlike? (ie there are no seas made out of molten sulfur, nor an atmosphere constituting entirely sulfur-based gases)
- Are there any other elements that could be injected into an Earthlike planet that still allow for carbon-based life that evolved in it to thrive while being toxic to creatures from Earth? If sulfur works for this setting, how would it play along with the sulfur as well?

Comment: I'm guessing it might be smellier...  (!)  Otherwise, I think your question is too broad & thus lacks focus. You're asking a dozen or more questions here: the Stack Exchange model is **you ask one focused worldbuilding question, we give you one reasonably reasonable anser.** Take a look at the [tour] and [help] so you can get a better idea how to formulate good questions. You've got an interesting question and a good basis, but right now it's just too much of a muchness.

Comment: Ah, all right! Thanks for the heads-up. I'll try to be more focused next time.

Comment: No worries! Feel free to start here. I'd rescind my vote to close if the query were made more focused. Also keep in mind, you can ask related, just not identical questions that fit within a worldbuilding theme!

Comment: Welcome! These are some awesome questions but as written this post is probably going to be closed. You can hit the edit button to hone this question more and still get useful answers!

Comment: Break this up into multiple separate queries. The second bulletin point alone is going to have lots of content for a good answer. The rule of “one question per post” is important as it will get your better responses!